# Best practice AWS access key and secret for applications

Tags: amazon-web-services, identity-management

What is the best practice for using the AWS and secret access keys when setting up the AWS application?

To get the access key and access secret, create an IAM account, but the IAM account is associated with a user, not with an application. What is the best to get an access key and access secret that is specific to an application (or different application environments, production, staging, etc.?) if the IAM users are meant to be for actual users and not for applications?

Comment: If the application runs on AWS compute (on EC2, Lambda, ECS etc.) then simply configure the launch of that compute to assume the relevant IAM role. Example for EC2 [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/iam-roles-for-amazon-ec2.html).

Comment: @jarmod That makes sense. In my case, it is regarding an S3 bucket I need access. So what is the best practice here? Which users access key and access secret should be used here since the IAM users, should not identify applications.

Comment: It's worth reading the information being shared with you. Applications typically don't use IAM users. They use IAM roles. IAM roles, like IAM users, are IAM principals that have associated IAM policies. You give the relevant AWS compute service (such as EC2 or Lambda) permission to assume an IAM role on your behalf. The service can then associate that role, and its permissions, with the compute instance (EC2 instance or Lambda function, for example). You don't need to supply IAM user credentials to your application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You wouldn't assign an IAM user to an application, typically you use an IAM Role.

To understand the difference, let us go through IAM basic knowledge

IAM controls: Who (authentication) can do What (authorization) **in your AWS account**.
Authentication(who) with IAM is done with users/groups and roles whereas authorization(what) is done by policies.

Here the term

- User - End user think about people
- Groups- a set of users under one set of permission(policies)
- Roles - are used to grant specific permission to specific actors for a set of duration of time. These actors can be **authenticated by AWS or some trusted external system.**

User and roles use policies for authorization. Keep in mind that user and role can't do anything until you allow certain actions with a policy.

Answer the following questions and you will differentiate between a user and a role:

- Can have a password? Yes-> user, No-> role
- Can have an access key? Yes-> user, No-> role
- Can belong to a group? Yes-> user, No -> role
- Can be associated with AWS resources (for example EC2 instances)? No-> user, Yes->role

AWS supports 3 Role Types for different scenarios

- AWS service roles (for example: EC2, Lambda, Redshift,...)
- Cross-Account Access: granting permissions to users from other AWS account, whether you control those account or not.
- Identity Provider Access: granting permissions to users authenticated by a trusted external system. AWS supports two kinds of identity federation:
  - Web-based identity such as Facebook, Goolge- IAM support ingeration via OpenID Connect
  - SAML 2.0 identity such as Active Directory, LDAP.

To understand what role is, you need to read its use case, I don't want to reinvent the wheel so please read the following AWS documents:
https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/how-to-use-a-single-iam-user-to-easily-access-all-your-accounts-by-using-the-aws-cli/

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_roles_providers_saml.html

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you, Lee. That cleared up a lot of stuff for me; my only question is now, after I have created a specific role for my application, I still need to have a user, that has the Access key and Access secret for my application. Which user should that be then, in production, staging, and developing locally???

Comment: If you mean a user who logs into an application, you can use Cognito to authenticate that user and allow them to assume the role which will provide them permissions.

Comment: No I meant an IAM user.

Comment: So, for example, if I need to add the access key and secret to my staging server, to access S3 for example. Which users access key and secret should be added on the server then??